# GPT disk with 2 Windows 10 LTSC Bootable partitions

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, gpt

I'm setting up a machine that requires 2 bootable partitions with a disk that's setup for GPT. The reason for 2 identical OS has to do with the applications that will be installed on each partition. One requires Internet access, the other is a local private LAN only. Each partition will run Windows 10 LTSC version. 
I know how to create the partition, and there's a bunch of tools out there that can copy the current boot partition (C:) to unused space on the disk for the second partition. My problem is I don't know how to tell bootmanager that I want the second partition to be bootable. It was easy when disks were MBR, but with GPT there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you clone an existing OS onto a newly created partition, the newly created OS will inherit all attributes from the one you cloned it from, including being bootable. Knowing that Windows sets the last-installed version as default, I'd clean-install one copy, set it up to your liking, update, programs and all the bells and whistles, THEN clone it onto the second partition, boot on it, and set its networking capabilities to your liking as well (LAN only, in this case). THEN, I'd select the one I want to boot from as default, depending on your use for Internet or not. Two birds, one stone.

Comment: With UEFI only the  install in ESP - efi system partition boots and then BCD has info to boot into other install. I have seen where users create a second FAT32 partition and move boot flag before second install. But then a bit of a hassle as you have to move boot flag back & forth to default boot Windows, or you can manually add each install to others BCD? It was used with grub & Linux to boot each Windows from grub menu. You may be able to use rEFInd to control booting & have them separate, (two FAT32 partitions). http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: In any case, you can dual-boot two different Windowses. It doesn't matter much which one is set as default, because that's something you can easily change, in System settings, with EasyBCD or any other way, so installing both is doable. Cloning is another matter, because most cloning software won't let you carbon-copy an existing OS/partition on a different volume if said volume isn't at least as big as the original one, even if you had plenty of empty space on it to begin with. Plus, you have to allow for some extra room for the cloning software to use as swap space. All don't work in RAM.